# Why does Joda-Time-2.3 return incorrect difference?

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime, difference

I am trying to find the difference between two dates and display it in the format 
"0 years 0 months 0 days 0 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds". I have created a method that takes two `DateTime` objects and return a string representing the difference.

Here is the method:

```
public static String getReadableDifference(DateTime start, DateTime end){

    int years = Years.yearsBetween(start, end).getYears();
    end = end.minusYears(years);
    int months = Months.monthsBetween(start, end).getMonths();
    end = end.minusMonths(months);
    int days = Days.daysBetween(start, end).getDays();
    end = end.minusDays(days);
    int hours = Hours.hoursBetween(start, end).getHours();
    end = end.minusHours(hours);
    int minutes = Minutes.minutesBetween(start, end).getMinutes();
    end = end.minusMinutes(minutes);
    int seconds = Seconds.secondsBetween(start, end).getSeconds();

    StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder(); 

    if(years != 0){
        returnString.append(years);
        returnString.append(" years ");
    }
    if(months != 0){
        returnString.append(months);
        returnString.append(" months ");
    }
    if(days != 0){
        returnString.append(days);
        returnString.append(" days ");
    }
    if(hours != 0){
        returnString.append(hours);
        returnString.append(" hours ");
    }
    if(minutes != 0){
        returnString.append(minutes);
        returnString.append(" minutes ");
    }
    if(seconds != 0){
        returnString.append(seconds);
        returnString.append(" seconds ");
    }

    return returnString.toString();
}
```

I then created two `DateTime` objects and calculated the difference using the method. If I initialize the `DateTime` objects as so, (`start`in this case equals `2014-03-28T12:56:38.137+01:00` and `end` would be read from a file in the full program.)

```
 DateTime start = new DateTime();
 DateTime end = DateTime.parse("2015-03-28T12:56:35.137+01:00");
```

the resulting output would be `11 months 31 days -3 seconds`, but if I initialized the `DateTime` objects like so,

```
DateTime now = DateTime.parse(new DateTime().toString());
DateTime end = DateTime.parse("2015-03-28T12:56:35.137+01:00");
```

the resulting output would be `11 months 30 days 23 hours 59 minutes 57 seconds` as would have been expected in the original initialization.

My Question is: Why does the first method of initialization produces the incorrect output, why did the second method produce the correct output, and why are the outputs not the same?

While it does not explain the issue, this is the method of getting the time difference that I decided to use:

```
 String string = new Period(start, end, PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime())
    .toString(new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .appendYears().appendSuffix(" year", " years").appendSeparator(" ")
    .appendMonths().appendSuffix(" month", " months").appendSeparator(" ")
    .appendDays().appendSuffix(" day", " days").appendSeparator(" ")
    .appendHours().appendSuffix(" hour", " hours").appendSeparator(" ")
    .appendMinutes().appendSuffix(" minute", " minutes").appendSeparator(" ")
    .appendSeconds().appendSuffix(" second", " seconds").toFormatter());
```

Comment: By curiosity, why don't you use `Interval`?

Comment: I am just learning how to use Joda-Time, how would you use the `Interval` object?

Comment: Be aware that `new DateTime()` always leads to different results because the current time changes (no halt on clock). So if you truly want to compare two different algorithms you should use a fixed start.

Comment: I did some research and found that the `Interval` object will fit my needs perfectly, doesn't explain the issue with my other method, but it fixs the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem must be somewhere else in your code, possibly you are modifying the start/now dates.

The following gives equal results:

```
    DateTime start = new DateTime();
    DateTime now = DateTime.parse(start.toString());
    DateTime end = DateTime.parse("2015-03-28T12:56:35.137+01:00");

    System.out.println("Start=" + start);
    System.out.println("Now  =" + now);
```

You can also use the Period from JodaTime to do the pretty printing, perhaps a bit easier to read:

```
    Period period = new Period(start, end, PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime());
    System.out.print(period.getYears() + " years, ");
    System.out.print(period.getMonths() + " months, ");
    // etc.
```

Comment: There is one problem. You should really specify `PeriodType`, otherwise there will be also week components.

Comment: Thanks @MenoHochschild, you are right. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. If you take a look at my last edit, you can see the method that I am now using and let me know if there is a more efficient way.